# Append a clone of a div to the child of an another div using $(this) selector

Tags: jquery, html

How can I clone a div to the child of an another div, and I may need to access the destination div by $(this).find(). My html structure is similar to

```
<div class="destination-wrapper">
  <div class="destination">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="source">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

So i need to clone the 'source' to the 'destination' When I click on the 'destination-wrapper'. There are many 'destination-wrapper' in the page, So I may need to use $(this).find('.destination')

the jquery I used is the following

```
$('.destination-wrapper').click(function(){
  $('.source').clone().appendTo($(this).find('.destination'));
});
```

Comment: _"Please correct me if my approach is wrong"_ - your approach of not describing what actually happens & how that differs from the expected result, is the wrong one to _ask a question_ - so please go read [ask]. // Assuming your non-existing problem description was actually saying that the number of elements appended seems to multiple after the first click ... well, that's because you _have_ more than one `.source` element in your document after the first click - so select which element(s) to clone a bit smarter - or store the element in a variable to begin with, https://jsfiddle.net/n281cgn9/

Answer (score 1):

Here, `$(this)` is referring to `$('.source')`. If you want to refer to `$('.destination-wrapper')`, you need to store it into a variable like :

```
$('.destination-wrapper').click(function(){
  var destination = $(this).find('.destination')
  $('.source').clone().appendTo(destination);
});
```

Comment: One problem, As i have mentioned in the question there are many 'destination-wrapper' and 'destination' within inside it. So it clones to all the the destination-wrapper, but i was hoping to clone the source only to the child of clicked destination-wrapper

Comment: Thanks for the help.. in some extend it helped

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, if `.source` is next element, after destination wrapper...

```
$('.destination-wrapper').click(function(){

destination=$(this).find('.destination');
  clone=$(this).next('.source').clone();
  clone.appendTo(destination);

});
```

Demo:

```js
$('.destination-wrapper').click(function(){

destination=$(this).find('.destination');
  clone=$(this).next('.source').clone();
  clone.appendTo(destination);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="destination-wrapper">
wrapper
  <div class="destination">
  destination
  </div>
</div>

<div class="source">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>


<div class="destination-wrapper">
wrapper
  <div class="destination">
  destination
  </div>
</div>

<div class="source">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It was not the first item, even though thanks for the tip it really helped.